Error showing - Body.Promise.reject(new FetchError(`invalid json response body at ${_this2.url} reason: ${err.message}`, 'invalid-json'));
Im working on sample project about decentralized wallet with Web3.js but when executing code its showing
**C:\Users\acer\Desktop\Training\Miniwallet\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:273
return Body.Promise.reject(new FetchError(invalid json response body at ${_this2.url}  reason: ${err.message}, 'invalid-json'));
^
FetchError: invalid json response body at https://go.getblock.io/cceb014f3b0b42f48b1e7f2c983b71d5/holesky/ reason: Unexpected end of JSON input
at C:\Users\acer\Desktop\Training\Miniwallet\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:273:32
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
type: 'invalid-json'
}
Node.js v18.16.0
**

require('dotenv').config();

const { Web3 } = require('web3');

const apikey = process.env['apikey'];
const network = 'holesky';
const node = `https://go.getblock.io/${apikey}/${network}/`;

const web3 = new Web3(node);

const accountTo = web3.eth.accounts.create();

const privatekey = process.env['privatekey'];
const accountFrom = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privatekey);
console.log(accountFrom);

const createSignedTx = async(rawTx)=>{
    rawTx.gas = await web3.eth.estimateGas(rawTx);
    return await accountFrom.signTransaction(rawTx);
}

const sendSignedTx = async (signedTx) => {
  return web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction);
}; 

const amountTo = "0.01";

const rawTx = {
    to:accountTo.address,
    value:web3.utils.toWei(amountTo,"ether")
}
createSignedTx(rawTx).then(sendSignedTx);

I will be grateful if i know how to solve this issue.
